# Omega Tools Transform Theme Name error

Tags: drush, theming, acquia-dev-desktop

I am getting the following error when trying to create an omega-sub-theme on my local machine (OSX) using drush on Acquia Dev Desktop.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _omega_tools_transform_theme_name()
```

Install process I followed goes:

1. Set Name
2. unique machine name
3. Omega (HTML5 base)
4. Default Starterkit
5. Destination: sites/all/themes
6. keep starterkit read me files
7. enable theme/ set as default
8. download libraries defined in libraries.make

Fatal error occurs here.

Comment: What version of Omega? If 3.x you need to install Omega Tools

Comment: Running Omega 4.x

Comment: Do you have Omega Tools installed? If so uninstall it (from the docs: _Omega 4.x should NOT be used with Omega Tools and Delta_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Clive's comment the error was Omega-Tools. I had disabled it but it required uninstalling and then I even had to delete the module from the modules directory to stop it from showing up in the modules page. After this I encountered this issue ( https://www.drupal.org/node/2200473 ) and then everything worked. Thanks Clive.